# WPF binding textbox to dictionary entry

Tags: wpf, binding, dictionary

i try to bind a wpf textbox to a dictionary placed in a viewmodel. The viewmodel is used as datacontext for the view.
I found a lot of examples and it sounds simple, but it will not work for me.

View:

> TextBox x:Name="txbTest" Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding MyDict[First]}"

ViewModel:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> MyDict = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"First", "Test1"},
            {"Second", "Test2"}
        };
```

I try all variants i found

```
Text="{Binding MyDict[First]}"
Text="{Binding Path=MyDict[First]}"
Text="{Binding MyDict[First].Text}"
Text="{Binding MyDict[First].Value}"
```

But nothing works, textbox is empty. Any idea?

Comment: You cannot bind to a field. Define `MyDict` as a property. I have shared the sample code in my answer.

Comment: Obviously, it can be so easy. Thank you, it works. I was guided fail by some examples.

Answer (score 35):

There is a Binding error in your code because `MyDict` is not a property. You have to bind to a `Property` and not to a `Field`

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'MyDict' property not found on 'object' ''MainWindow' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=MyDict[First]; DataItem='MainWindow' (Name=''); target element is 'TextBox' (Name='textBox1'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

Change the MyDict `Field` to a `Property` like shown below

```
    private Dictionary<string, string> _MyDict;

    public Dictionary<string, string> MyDict
    {
        get { return _MyDict; }
        set { _MyDict = value; }
    }
```

In the constructor of your `ViewModel` initialize MyDict.

```
        MyDict = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"First", "Test1"},
            {"Second", "Test2"}
        };
```

The following two variants will not work as MyDict["key"] returns a `string` and `string` does not have a `Text` or `Value` property. The other two variants should work.

```
Text="{Binding MyDict[First].Text}"
Text="{Binding MyDict[First].Value}"
```

The following bindings will work

```
Text="{Binding MyDict[First]}"
Text="{Binding Path=MyDict[First]}"
```

Comment: Obviously, it can be so easy. Thank you, it works. I was guided fail by some examples.

Comment: How would you go about doing this programatically? Say I dynamically create the textbox and the dictionary.

Comment: @estebro Follow other guides for programmatic binding and then just specify the dictionary element as the binding property.