# Dictionary - TextBox binding is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I am not using a view model, there is a similar post that uses a view model and I tried to do it based on that but it is not working,
[WPF binding textbox to dictionary entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18141527/wpf-binding-textbox-to-dictionary-entry)

When I click my button, I have a list that is created and then a dictionary is formed, so in my trimmed down example to get it to work, I have the dictionary to be created on the button click

**CODE BEHIND**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
private Dictionary<string, string> _MyDict;


    public Dictionary<string, string> MyDict        {
        get { return _MyDict; }
        set { _MyDict= value; }
    }
 private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      MyDict = new Dictionary<string, string>
       { 
          {"First", "Test1"},
          {"Second", "Test2"}
       };
    }
  }
```

**XAML**

```
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="674.167">
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="createListfromTextFile" Content="hi" Click="button_Click"/>

    <TextBox x:Name="textBox1"  Text="{Binding MyDict[First], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="279" >

</Grid>
```

**UPDATE**

Following Chrille's comment I fixed the problem,
by implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` like so:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

 public Dictionary<string, string> MyDict
    {
        get { return _MyDict; }
        set {

            _MyDict = value;
            if (null != PropertyChanged)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs  ("MyDict"));
            }
        }          
     }
  }
```

Comment: Your are basically using a view model, your MainWindow class (DataContext). The view model class needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged to notify the UI about changes.

Comment: @Chrille, yes you are right... that worked, thank you - sorry I am a newbie with this stuff

Comment: @JohnChris Instead of editing the question you should write an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Clemens, ok cool, I changed it- was hoping Chrille would post an answer so I can mark it accepted, but he never did :(

Comment: Sorry, I posted an answer now

Comment: Don't, pls.  Dictionaries are terrible for binding against.

Comment: @Will, what would you suggest then?

Comment: If I need to index into the collection by a key, I either just use a regular ObservableCollection and FirstOrDefault it (really, it's almost always fast enough), or I create a custom collection that extends KeyedCollection and implements INotifyCollectionChanged.  KC Is an IEnumerable<T> where T can be whatever you want, which works great with DataTemplates.  Dictionaries are all IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<k,v,>>, so you cannot take easy advantage of automatic data template selection.

Comment: @Will, Could you post/link an example of a custom collection that extends keyed collection and implements INotifyCollectionChanged? Just so I can test it out:)

Comment: @JohnChris Search engines are your friend.  http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2010/01/12/make-keyedcollectionlttkey-titemgt-to-work-properly-with-wpf-data-binding.aspx I haven't used this impl, but it's not hard to do. That should give you a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MainWindow class (DataContext) needs to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> MyDict
    {
        get { return _MyDict; }
        set 
        {
            _MyDict = value;
            PropertyChanged?.(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyDict"));
        }         
    }
}
```

Or even better, create a separate class for the viewmodel and inherit from ViewModelBase or similar:

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(params string[] propertyName)
        {
            foreach (var prop in propertyName)
            {
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, args);
            }
        }
    }
```

And finally in the setter:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> MyDict
{
    get { return _MyDict; }
    set 
    {
        _MyDict = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("MyDict");
    }         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following Chrille's comment I fixed the problem, by implementing INotifyPropertyChanged like so:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
    public MainWindow()
   {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
   }

 public Dictionary<string, string> MyDict
 {
    get { return _MyDict; }
    set {

        _MyDict = value;
        if (null != PropertyChanged)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs  ("MyDict"));
        }
    }          
 }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The main reason that i found in your code is that, you forgot to implement the interface, if you implement them in a proper way means your code will get worked. Try the following:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    // include your code here

    // change the property definition as like this:
   public Dictionary<string, string> MyDict       
   {
       get { return _MyDict; }
       set 
       {
          _MyDict= value; 
          NotifyPropertyChanged("MyDict");  
       }
   }

    // interface implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```